# Hiding an element with jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to create a script to develop a chained select, but the simplest thing doesn't work. Note that a know very little about js and jquery.

I create my dropdown list with CodeIgniter: `<?php echo form_dropdown('city', array(), "", 'id="ciudades"'); ?>`

Then load the script:

```
if (isset($add_select_sources))
{
    echo "
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='" . $root_path . "js/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='" . $root_path . "js/select.js'></script>
    ";
}
```

I am sure that add_select_sources is true, it is tested.

And then my select.js: `$('#ciudades').hide();`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that your javascript is being executed after jQuery is being included.

Also, you should execute your jQuery within a "Document Ready closure":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ciudades').hide();
});
```

There have been issues with people trying to do this. So there are some more things I'd like to suggest:

- Make sure that your elements have a width/height/display-block etc
- Try $('#ciudades').show().hide(); as some people have had that issue too!
- console.log() your events to see if they are being fired:

> ```
>     $(document).ready(function(){
>         console.log('doc ready');
>         $('#ciudades').show().hide();
>         console.log('element hidden');
>     });
> ```

Also, why are you using PHP to echo out script tags?

Comment: `$('#ciudades').show().hide();` totally worked! Thanks!! I'm using echo because it's in a php if.

Answer (score 2):

This will easily do.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourEelementId').hide();
});
```